# Passing an array as a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameters

I have a function that takes an array of fixed size. The contents of the array will be modified in this function so I want to pass the array as a pointer.

Here are the definitions of my arrays:

```
int u[] = {1, 0 , a};   //a is an integer
int v[] = {1, 0 , a};   //a is an integer
```

Here is my prototype:

```
void New_Values(int* u[3], int* v[3], const int q);
```

Here is my function call:

```
New_Values(&u, &v, q);   //q is an integer
```

I get the compiler errors:

> passing argument 1 of ‘New_Values’ from incompatible pointer type

and

> passing argument 2 of ‘New_Values’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only exceptionally will you want to pass a pointer to an array to a function; you'll most likely do as the others have suggested:

```
void New_Values(int u[], int v[], int q);
void New_Values(int *u,  int *v,  int q);
```

(These declarations are equivalent; the compiler treats the former as if it was written like the latter, so most often you'll see simple pointer notation rather than array notation.)

And the call:

```
New_Values(u, v, q);
```

If you really want to play with pointers to arrays, you have to use the correct notation — what you tried to specify was an array of integer pointers, not a pointer to an array of integers.

```
void New_Values(int (*v)[], int (*v)[], int q);
```

And the call:

```
New_Values(&u, &v, q);
```

Inside `New_Values()`, you'd use:

```
(*v)[i] = (*u)[j] + q;
```

This is an illustration of C's 'declaration syntax matches syntax when used'.

Note that I dropped the `const` from the `int` parameter.  It isn't completely pointless, but there's no danger of the called function modifying a value in the calling function if it does modify the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the function take pointers:

```
void New_Values(int *u, int *v, const int q);
```

And just use them like arrays. In this context the array decays into a pointer to the first element. Also, you should drop the `&` from the function call and just say: `New_Values(u, v, q);`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the array names as arrays decay into pointers.

Pass as:

```
New_Values(u, v, q);
```

and function prototype:

```
void New_Values(int* u, int* v, const int q);
```